# C#: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, сокет, smtp

Добрый день.

Я разработал SMTP windows service, который получает на вход эл. письмо, а на выходе отдает СМС с данными из этого письма.

Получается, что иногда я получаю такую ошибку

> : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

в процедуре:

```
/// <summary>
/// Отправить ответ клиенту
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data"></param>
private void SendData(string data)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] byte_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToCharArray());
        _clientSocket.Send(byte_data, byte_data.Length, 0); // ОШИБКА
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logHelper.WriteEvent("Smtp.StartProcessing.SendData ошибка: " + ex.ToString());
    }   
}
```

**Замечу, что эта ошибка появляется очень редко и она не фатальна ,кажется, но мне хотелось бы знать возможные причины, из-за которых эта ошибка может  возникать.**

буду признателен за ответы.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Любопытно, не поленился и загуглил.

Судя по всему вам необходимо либо обрабатывать эту ошибку и повторять действие вновь, либо ошибка в ms tcp стеке, тогда стоит попробовать подредактировать реестр:

В узел `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\`
Добавить параметр `SynAttackProtect` типа `DWORD` со значением `00000000`

Но говорят, что ключ может не использоваться, подробнее: [Registry Settings that can be Modified to Improve Operating System Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377058(BTS.10).aspx)

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что отключение защиты от SYN attack через реестр является хорошим советом?

Comment: Нет, но нам неизвестна инфраструктура. Там уж пусть сами решают)